# R group repeating values

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, melt

If I am dealing with a dataset like this

```
  Id     Index    Value
  1233   i1       Blue
  1233   i2       Blue
  1233   i3       Blue
  6545   i1       Red
  6545   i2       NA
  6545   i3       Black
  4177   i1       NA
  4177   i2       NA 
  4177   i2       NA
```

How do I create a new dataset by retaining only one instance of repeating values for Id like 1233 and 4177 like this below.

```
  Id     Index    Value
  1233   i        Blue
  6545   i1       Red
  6545   i2       NA
  6545   i3       Black
  4177   i        NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df1, Id, Value, .keep_all = TRUE)
#    Id Index Value
#1 1233    i1  Blue
#2 6545    i1   Red
#3 6545    i2  <NA>
#4 6545    i3 Black
#5 4177    i1  <NA>
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[c('Id', 'Value')]),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(1233L, 1233L, 1233L, 6545L, 6545L, 6545L, 
4177L, 4177L, 4177L), Index = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i1", "i2", 
"i3", "i1", "i2", "i2"), Value = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", 
NA, "Black", NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: nice with `duplicated`! +1

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks, it is a nice option using row index `+1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `unique` + `rownames` can help you

```
df[as.numeric(rownames(unique(df[-2]))),]
```

such that

```
    Id Index Value
1 1233    i1  Blue
4 6545    i1   Red
5 6545    i2  <NA>
6 6545    i3 Black
7 4177    i1  <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1233L, 1233L, 1233L, 6545L, 6545L, 6545L, 
4177L, 4177L, 4177L), Index = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i1", "i2", 
"i3", "i1", "i2", "i2"), Value = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", 
NA, "Black", NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table` package and the `by` argument of its `unique` method:

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by = c("Id", "Value"))
#       Id  Index  Value
# 1:  1233     i1   Blue
# 2:  6545     i1    Red
# 3:  6545     i2   <NA>
# 4:  6545     i3  Black
# 5:  4177     i1   <NA>
```